# what is the most efficient way in pyspark to reduce a dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following dataframe with the two first row looking like:

```
['station_id', 'country', 'temperature', 'time']
['12', 'usa', '22', '12:04:14']
```

I want to display the average temperature by descending order of the first 100 stations in 'france'.

What is the best way (Most efficient) to do it in pyspark?

Comment: What have you tried, seems like `filter`, `map`, `reduceByKey` and `sortBy` would work.

Comment: you mean the column titles and first row?

Comment: Yeah the first one is the column title

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We translate your query to `Spark SQL` in the following way:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean, desc

df.filter(df["country"] == "france") \ # only french stations
  .groupBy("station_id") \ # by station
  .agg(mean("temperature").alias("average_temp")) \ # calculate average
  .orderBy(desc("average_temp")) \ # order by average 
  .take(100) # return first 100 rows
```

Using the `RDD` API and anonymous functions:

```
df.rdd \
  .filter(lambda x: x[1] == "france") \ # only french stations
  .map(lambda x: (x[0], x[2])) \ # select station & temp
  .mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)) \ # generate count
  .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1])) \ # calculate sum & count
  .mapValues(lambda x: x[0]/x[1]) \ # calculate average
  .sortBy(lambda x: x[1], ascending = False) \ # sort
  .take(100)
```

Comment: And without spark sql?

Comment: Do you mean using `rdd` api, why if you have a `DataFrame` ?

Comment: Actually that just the instructions I had. My code is pretty messy I defined functions and all, I think there is a easier way that's why I asked here.